# any another alternative code to work for http trigger function app read service bus message do not want to use service bus trigger

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I `do not want to use service bus trigger` using `.net code http trigger function app` to read messages from topic.

> Run below code locally or deploy it on azure portal. send a message
>   into topic/sub it will read messages successfully.
>
> wait for 1 minute
>   again send messages to topic/sub , it wont read messages from
>   topic/sub. if running locally keep fucntion running and make a http
>   call.

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string serviceBusConnectionString = "connectionstring";
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, "topicName/subscriptions/subscriptionName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null, 500);

            var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            if (messages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in messages)
                {
                    await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(item.SystemProperties.LockToken);
                }

            }
            return new OkObjectResult("");
        }
    }
```

Is there another code which will work for .net code http trigger function app?

Comment: anyone here who can give me any solution based on http trigger? should i use SubscriptionClient for .net core 2.0 function app will that be fine?

Comment: I really don't get the question. What is the desired behavior and what is the current issue?

Comment: to reproduce issue please create a new Http trigger function app and copy paste the given code. Now run the Http function locally. send a message into topic and hit manually Http function using localhost url , put a debugger at function app you can able to see it is reading messages from topic. now issue is here - do not close running function app send again new messages to topic and again hit Http trigger localhost url debugger will hot again and you can observe messages are null though there are messages into topic that is the issue it is not reading it again.

Comment: So the function is just returning without processing any messages? Could you check if you don't have any instance processing those messages? Also, with such an implementation, you would have to keep note of the [service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#service-limits) that you might hit like the HTTP request timeout of 230 seconds. Instead using [durable functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) would be a better approach here.